# Wave Equation with FDM, Matlab

Tags: matlab, differential-equations, numerical-analysis

I am trying to implement matlab code to solve the wave equation, my function looks like this:

```
function [x,t,w] = wave_eqn(xl,xr,yb,yt,M,N,f,l,r,p)
% input: space interval [xl,xr], time interval [yb,yt]
% number of space steps M, number of time steps N 
% output: solution w 
D=2;                        % diffusion coefficient
h=(xr-xl)/M; k=(yt-yb)/N; m=M-1; n=N;
sigma=D*k/(h*h);
a=diag(1-2*sigma*ones(m,1))+diag(sigma*ones(m-1,1),1);
a=a+diag(sigma*ones(m-1,1),-1); % define matrix a
lside=l(yb+(0:n)*k); rside =r(yb+(0:n)*k);
w(:,1)=f(xl+(1:m)*h)';  % initial conditions
for j=1:n
    w(:,j+1)=a*w(:,j)-w(:,j-1)+sigma^2*[lside(j);zeros(m-2,1);rside(j)];
end
w=[lside;w;rside];      % attach boundary conds
x=(0:m+1)*h;t=(0:n)*k;
% view(60,30);axis([xl xr yb yt -1 1])
end

%source: numerical analysis 2nd edition
```

I keep getting an error at the equation in the for loop with the w(:,j-1) term that says: Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

I am not quite sure how to fix this problem. It should also be noted that f,p,l,r are all inputted functions of x and t. I used a template for the heat equation to make this code, but I am not sure how to implement the fourth function, p. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are looping over `1:n`, so `j-1=0` and `0` is not a valid index in Matlab.

Instead, loop from `2:n-1` to also account for the `j+1` term.

You have already declared your initial condition `w(:,1)`, but your numerical method requires 2 previous steps, so you will also need to assign an initial condition to `w(:,2)`, possibly as simple as `w(:,2) = w(:,1)`. Then loop using:

```
for j=2:n-1
    w(:,j+1)=a*w(:,j)-w(:,j-1)+sigma^2*[lside(j);zeros(m-2,1);rside(j)];
end
```